# C++ Data Read From File Has a Large Gap?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a text file that contains Strings and and Ints as follows:

```
test1 1
test2 2
test3 3
test4 4
test5 5
test6 6
```

Tests 1-4 were all written into the text file prior to running the program, while tests 5 and 6 are appended to the file by the writeHighScore() function.  Within the text file tests 5 and 6 look perfect, but when I read them back into the console with readHighScore() there are a large amount of newlines (approx 10) in between test 4 and test 5.  Interestingly, the test 5 and test 6 are displayed with the correct spacing:

```
test1 1
test2 2
test3 3
test4 4





test5 5
test6 6
```

Here are the two functions:

```
void writeHighScore(Player p)
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("highscores.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    if (outputFile.is_open())
    {
        outputFile << "\r" << endl << p.getName() << " " << p.getHealth() * 10;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nError file not found!";
    }
    outputFile.close();
}

void readHighScores()
{
    string name;
    int score;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("highscores.txt");

    cout << "\n\n\nHIGH SCORES" << endl;
    cout << "-----------" << endl;  
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inputFile, name, ' ');
        inputFile >> score;
        cout << name << "\t\t" << setw(3) << score << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you inspect the file to determine that it looks perfect?

Comment: It's a text file so I just open it and check for correct spacing.  Everything looked normal.

Comment: Did you check for whitespace at the end of `test4 4`?

Comment: That was it.  It appeared fine using the mouse but after using the arrow keys from the very start something funny was going on at the end of test 4.  That's embarrassing.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some unnoticed whitespace in a data file, and is unlikely to be of any value to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most probably spaces and/or tabs after `test4 4` that are taking one line each as you are interleaving `<< endl;` while printing them. Remove `<< endl;` and you'd see the output having whitespaces in between.

They are creeping in because you are using both newline and carriage return in `<< "\r" << endl`.

Answer (score 0):

`endl` and `\r` is adding extra newlines into your file . try to remove these from from your `outputFile` statement.